# Token expiration for server-to-server flow

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api, accesstoken

We have implemented a server-to-server flow in Java where our API server will make calls to Salesforce API. We followed [the great example provided by Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5). However, there are two time-related questions that we cannot seem to find a good answer to.

Ultimately, the question we want to answer is: **when do the Access Tokens we get expire?**

The only notion of time we see in the example is the `exp` claim on the JWT. Are we free to set it to whatever we want? Are there best practices? Does that control the expiration of the Access Token we get?
Or is there a way to know when the given Access Token is set to expire (maybe via another API call)?

We have currently hard-coded our Access Token to expire after 15 minutes. We have seen our first failure to get a new token in about 6 months. Not a huge deal, but it did prompt us to revisit and make sure that as we scale up our usage, we are not going to have more failures.

We did take a look at [some](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350244/oauth-flow-for-server-to-server-calls) of the [suggestions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306455/access-token-expiration-semantics) from Stack Overflow, but none of them seem to address our question

Comment: there is a great answer provided by sfdcfox [Why does my salesforce access token expire after a certain time?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335786/why-does-my-salesforce-access-token-expire-after-a-certain-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exp` provided in the JWT tells you when *the JWT itself expires*, not the epxiration time of the access token you get as a result of exchanging the JWT. You need to set the JWT expiry far enough in the future so that it can get to Salesforce before it expires (so give yourself at least 15 seconds) but not so far in the future that it becomes a security issue. Start by giving yourself something like 30 seconds.

The access token has a timeout controlled by:

1. The connected app you're using for the JWT flow
2. The individual User record in the org you're connecting to
3. The org-wide security settings

The maximum timeout is 24 hours (and I think the minimum is 15 minutes).

The timeout used is the one that's first encountered (so if you don't define a timeout in the connected app, Salesforce will look for a timeout at the User level).

As pointed to in the comments, if you use the access token to make a call to Salesforce after at least 50% of the timeout has elapsed (and obviously before the timeout has completely elapsed), the timeout will be reset.  Make requests frequent enough, and your access token is functionally immortal (for better or worse).